# Send php variable onclick through javascript code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form table, in which when I click on **Show** button, then a popup window open. Till now everything is good.

But after click on **Show** button, I also want to send php variable in popup window and want to show values related to that variable. How it can be possible?

**My table is below**

```
<table align="center">
    <?php 
       include("connection.php");
       $query1=mysql_query("select * from career") or die(mysql_error());
       while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
       {
            extract($row1);
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td>Designation</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="des" value="<?php echo $designation; ?>"></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Number of position</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="des" value="<?php echo $no_of_position; ?>"></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Experience</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="des" value="<?php echo $experience; ?>"></td>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Qualification</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="des" value="<?php echo $qualification; ?>"></td>
        </td>
    <tr>
        <td>Job profile</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="des" value="<?php echo $job_profile; ?>"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo"$id"; ?></td>
        <td><button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;" id="id1">Show</button>
       </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

In above code when I click on Show Button, then popup window open, code is below:

```
<div id="id01" class="modal1">
    <form class="modal1-content animate" action="xyz.php">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close modal1">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
           <div>Content</div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    // Get the modal1
    var modal1 = document.getElementById('id01');

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal1, close it
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal1) {
            modal1.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
</script>
```

I want to send **id variable**, by which I can fetch values from database in popup window.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for reply...How can I use jquery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need an ajax call to a php page like this:

**modalService.php**

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']){
     echo "no request";
     exit;
}
$id = $_GET['id'];
//Do your query and echo the modal content
```

**table**

```
<td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
<td>
    <button onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $id; ?>')" >Show</button>
 </td>
```

**JS**

```
function myFunction(id){
    var modal = document.getElementById("id01");
    modal!==null && (modal.style.display="block");
    var modalServiceUrl = "./modalService.php?id="+id;
    //xhr to get modalService
}
```

**EDIT: USING JQUERY**

```
<button data-queryid="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="showModal">Show</button>

jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var modal = document.getElementById("id01");
    $("button.showModal").on("click", function(){
        modal.fadeIn();
        var id = $(this).attr("data-queryid");
        var modalServiceUrl = "./modalService.php?id="+id;
        modal.load(modalServiceUrl);
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you for reply......But by id01, popup window shows and I want another php variable id to send popup window and want to show value of php variable id.

Comment: onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'"     here is the id01. If I remove it, then popup will not show

Comment: <td><?php echo"$id"; ?></td>   here is another id, which is fetched from database and it is php variable. Now I want when I click  Show button, then this id (PHP variable) should be send on popup window. By which I can show values from database by this id.

Comment: Now popup is not opening

Comment: can we please connect with team viewer?

Comment: ok......thankyou....when you are free.. please connect with team viewer

Comment: id:  589 769 950                  password: 1625